# how can I access the warnings-ng plugin tokens?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am learning jenkins on my own and I do not have much experience. I just found out about warnings-ng plugin and I am trying to get acces to tokens in my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('analysis') {
            steps {
                script{
                    bat'''
                        cppcheck "C:/Users/anton/Desktop/railway"  --xml --xml-version=2 . 2> cppcheck.xml
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Test'){
            steps {
                script {
                    def cppCheck = scanForIssues tool: cppCheck(pattern: 'cppcheck.xml')
                    publishIssues issues: [cppCheck]
                    echo "${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT}"
              
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

as mentioned in the warnings-ng [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#token-macro-support) but I get an error `No such property: ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT for class: groovy.lang.Binding` how would be the right syntax to access the token? or is there anything needed to do before accessing to it, as far as I understood I just need the token macro plugin installed, which I have, and the warnings-ng plugin provided those tokens to be accessible, am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use tm step.

```
def newIssuesCountString = tm stringWithMacro: '${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT, type="NEW"}'
int newIssuesCount = newIssuesCountString as int
def totalIssuesCountString = tm stringWithMacro: '${ANALYSIS_ISSUES_COUNT, type="TOTAL"}'
int totalIssuesCount = totalIssuesCountString as int
```

reference1 : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/token-macro/

reference2 : https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#token-macro-support